# AKKA `Http().singleRequest` may stuck on one node

Tags: scala, http, akka, httprequest, actor

### Short story:

In a 2-node Kubernetes AKKA clustering setup, each node runs a piece of code that calls a Kubeless function as follows:

```
log.trace("Calling URL [{}] with bytes response.", address)
Http().singleRequest(
  request = HttpRequest(
    method = HttpMethods.POST,
    uri = address,
    entity = HttpEntity(contentType, data)
  ),
  connectionContext = noCertificateCheckContext
)
```

The above code generates the following log on the *good* node:

```
Calling URL [http://10.233.54.59:8080] with bytes response.

[t-dispatcher-22] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: Creating pool.

[t-dispatcher-22] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: Dispatching request [POST Strict(14160 bytes)] to pool

[t-dispatcher-21] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: [0 (Unconnected)]Dispatching request [POST / Strict(14160 bytes)]

[t-dispatcher-21] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: [0 (Unconnected)]Before event [onNewRequest] In state [Unconnected] for [0 ms]

[t-dispatcher-21] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: [0 (Unconnected)]Establishing connection

[t-dispatcher-21] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: [0 (Connecting)]After event [onNewRequest] State change [Unconnected] -> [Connecting]

[t-dispatcher-14] [36mr$$anonfun$receive$1[m: Resolving 10.233.54.59 before connecting

[...]
```

...and each of these calls succeeds.

The above code generates the following code on the *bad* node:

```
Calling URL [http://10.233.54.59:8080] with bytes response.
```

...and literally nothing after that. The *bad* node can accept incoming requests through its HTTP API written in AKKA and can do all things, but not `Http().singleRequest`, which is used to call Kubeless functions.

The *only difference between the *good* and the *bad* node* is that the *bad* node first starts an AKKA `Cluster` object for a short amount of time, does some stuff with it, then tears it down.

```
system.terminate()
Await.result(system.whenTerminated, timeout)
```

...and then it starts it again. The cluster can then be formed between the two nodes. Both nodes report that they are in a cluster and can gossip properly.

The *bad* node can not perform HTTP requests even from the first one. HTTP entities are properly subscribed using `response.entity.toStrict(20 seconds)` or `response.discardEntityBytes()`.

Hints or ideas on how to fix/debug the problem further are much appreciated!

### More details:

I start one AKKA cluster on Kubernetes using the following dependencies:

```
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-metrics" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-typed" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-typed" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-sharding-typed" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-typed" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-discovery" % "2.6.16",
    "com.lightbend.akka.management" %% "akka-management-cluster-bootstrap" % "1.1.1",
    "com.lightbend.akka.discovery" %% "akka-discovery-kubernetes-api" % "1.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.6.16",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.6.16" % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.2.6",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "10.2.6",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.2.6",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.2.6",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.2.6" % "test",
```

Below is the default configuration.

```
akka {
  test {
    timefactor =  3.0
  }

  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
  log-config-on-start = on

  http {
    parsing {
      uri-parsing-mode = strict
      error-logging-verbosity = full
    }
    server {
      server-header = ""
      verbose-error-messages = on
      idle-timeout = 60s
      max-connections = 2048
      request-timeout = 30s
      websocket.periodic-keep-alive-mode = pong
    }
    host-connection-pool {
      max-connections = 32
      max-open-requests = 64
      max-connection-lifetime = 10 min
      keep-alive-timeout = 10 min
      response-entity-subscription-timeout = 2.second
    }
    routing {
      verbose-error-messages = on
    }
  }

  discovery {
    method = config
  }

  management {
    cluster.bootstrap {
      contact-point-discovery {
        service-name = "local-cluster"
        discovery-method = config
        required-contact-point-nr = 1
      }
    }
  }

  actor {
    allow-java-serialization = on
    warn-about-java-serializer-usage = off
    provider = "cluster"
    blocking-dispatcher {
      type = "Dispatcher"
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 32
        parallelism-max = 128
      }
      throughput = 1
    }
  }

  cluster {
    min-nr-of-members = 1
    log-info-verbose = off
    sharding {
      passivate-idle-entity-after = off
    }
  }

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    artery {
      transport = tcp
      canonical.port = 0
      bind.port = 0
      bind.bind-timeout = 10s
    }
  }

  extensions = [
    "akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension",
    "akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub"
  ]
}
```

On Kubernetes, the configuration is overwritten with the following:

```
          akka {
            discovery {
              kubernetes-api {
                pod-label-selector = "app=my-app"
                pod-domain = "cluster.local"
              }
            }

            management {
              cluster.bootstrap {
                contact-point-discovery {
                  discovery-method = kubernetes-api
                  service-name = ${?AKKA_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVICE_NAME}
                  service-namespace = "staging.svc.cluster.local"
                  interval = 10 seconds
                  required-contact-point-nr = 0
                }
              }
            }

            cluster {
              configuration-compatibility-check.enforce-on-join = off
              shutdown-after-unsuccessful-join-seed-nodes = 120s
              downing-provider-class = "akka.cluster.sbr.SplitBrainResolverProvider"
              sharding {
                use-lease = "akka.coordination.lease.kubernetes"
              }
              split-brain-resolver {
                active-strategy = "lease-majority"
                lease-majority {
                  lease-implementation = "akka.coordination.lease.kubernetes"
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the http request via the new actor system vs. through the one that's been terminated?  Note that `Http()` uses an `implicit` actor system.  I am curious why you terminate the actor system in the middle.

Comment: @LeviRamsey, the first actor system (AKKA cluster for that matter) is created by a `playground` mechanism that simulates a running application in order to inject demo data into the application. When the `playground` procedure finishes, the simulation is finished and the AKKA cluster is terminated. Then, shortly after, the AKKA cluster is started again, but it then will be started by the standard application bootstrap procedure. The "old" system is not used afterward. I also checked and the new and the old system has the same name. Would that be a problem? Could there be anything leftover?

Comment: @LeviRamsey I checked global objects again to make sure and I found a reference that was sticking around and still held the old actor system. I think I got the problem, but I have to revalidate it again in the development environment. I'm 99% confident now that this was the problem. Thanks for your suggestion! Would you please formulate your suggestion as an answer to this thread so that I can upvote it and possibly accept as solution after I confirmed it in a few hours?